# How to create a Web slice with Search?

Tags: ie8-webslice

Does anyone know how bing's [weather webslice](http://ieaddons.com/it/Details.aspx?Id=909) search works? I am attempting to create a web slice(only available in IE8) with search built in and I have read that forms are not allowed and neither is javascript.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create active content by defining it on another page using the entry-content rel attribute of an  tag.  In this example slice.aspx has JavaScript code on it.

```
<div class="hslice" id="MySlice">
    <p class="entry-title">
        My Active Slice</p>
     <a rel="entry-content" href="slice.aspx" />
    <div class="entry-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar effect using some simple javascript in a Chrome extension to create an [Arbitrary Web Slice](http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=450) extension but with the advantage of being able to take any slice out of any web page, not just predefined Web Slice areas like Bing weather.  Obviously only works in Chrome but Firefox has a similar extension API in GreaseMonkey.